# Calling function on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding an input field dynamically where you can add an URL which is loaded into an Iframe.

I want to add the URL either on clicking a button (that works) or on pressing enter in the input field (that does not work).

The function does not get called. Why is that?

```js
$( ".button-2" ).mouseup(function() {
    $("#content").append('<div><div>Please insert URL</div><br><input type="text" class="url_eingeben" value="http://"><br><button class="bestaetigen" >Confirm</button></div>');  
});

function addURL(){
    var url = $(this).prevAll('input').val();
    $(this).parent().closest('div').html('<iframe src="'+url+'" name=""></iframe>'); 
}

$( "#content" ).on("click", ".bestaetigen", addURL); // This works
$( "#content" ).on("keyup", ".url_eingeben", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        alert("Enter has been pressed"); 
        addURL(); // This does not work
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="logo">
        ...
        </div>

        <div id="whatever">
        ...
        </div>

        <div>
            <button class="button-2">Add the input</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're not calling addURL. Change `addURL;` to `addURL();`

Comment: What @Paulpro said. Whad did you expect `addURL;` to do?

Comment: @Paulpro I did that, but it still does not work.

Comment: @cerbrus I want it to add the Iframe. The same thing it does already on clicking the confirm button.

Comment: Add a breakpoint before the call, to see if the execution reaches that piece of code..

Comment: @callback I dont know what a breakpoint is but if I add an alert for the key press, the alert triggers but the addURL() does not seem to happen. Maybe the selector is wrong because the click refers to the button and the keyup to the input field ...

Comment: yes, you need to make sure `$(this)` refers to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your below functions from

```
function addURL(){
var url = $(this).prevAll('input').val();
$(this).parent().closest('div').html('<iframe src="'+url+'" name="">
</iframe>'); 
}

$( "#content" ).on("click", ".bestaetigen", addURL); // This works
$( "#content" ).on("keyup", ".url_eingeben", function(e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
    alert("Enter has been pressed"); 
    addURL();   // This does not work
}
});
```

To:

```
function addURL(obj, url){

obj.parent().closest('div').html('<iframe src="'+url+'" name=""></iframe>'); 
}

$( "#content" ).on("click", ".bestaetigen", function(e){
var url=$(this).prevAll('input').val();
    addURL($(this), url); // This will work
}
); 
$( "#content" ).on("keyup", ".url_eingeben", function(e) {

if (e.which == 13) {
var url=$(this).val();
    addURL($(this), url);    // This will work
}
});
```

Comment: It does not find the URLs when I do it with enter.

Answer (score 1):

Change method addURL() to this one (calling $(this) will not work from keyup point of view becouse it is a textbox in this case):

```
function addURL(){

   var url = $('.bestaetigen').prevAll('input').val();
   $('.bestaetigen').parent().closest('div').html('<iframe src="'+url+'" name=""></iframe>'); 
}
```

and replace this:

```
if (e.which == 13) {
    addURL; // This does not work
}
```

to this:

```
if (e.which == 13) {
    addURL();   // This does not work
}
```

Comment: Well, now I have issues because I can add several inputsand the call does not work anymore if I have more than one open. But I will figure it out I suppose ...